# How to solve error 0x8007000e while updating to windows 10 1903 from 1809?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1809, windows-10-v1903, windows-10-1809

Yesterday windows update asked me whether i want to update my window to 1903. I clicked "download and install". It downloaded the whole update and after installing upto 27%, the windows update itself crashed. When I opened it from the settings, it says, the failed to install with error code 0x8007000e and i should try after restarting the system.

I've already tried following steps, still the error persists.
- restarted my laptop
- update all the drivers using Driver Easy
- done SFC, and it says it repaired the corrupted files
- my c drive has more than 30gb of free space
- there is no external storage device connected to the pc

Comment: "it says it repaired the corrupted files" - Which files did it repair?  I suggest you use the Upgrade Assistant in a case like this.  After you use the Disk Cleanup tool to remove the temporary files from the last attempt.

Comment: You can always open the log file. It will be very specific on why the upgrade failed.

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-feature-update-failed-with-error-code-0x8007000e

Comment: @LPChip where can i find that log file?

Comment: If you navigate to the following folder: C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\Panther you'll find a file called setuperror.log

Answer (score 0):

Error code 0x8007000e may indicate system corruption.
This is supported by the fact that SFC found some corrupted files, although it
might not have been able to find or repair all of them.

You may try to run the Windows Update Troubleshooter, found in
*Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Windows Update*,
and this might repair the problem.

If it doesn't help, there are several more manipulations that you may do using the
[DISM command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14),
as described in the article
[How to Repair Windows 10 Image using DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html).

As your system is corrupted and Windows Update does not work,
you cannot use DISM via the Internet with Windows Update and would require a local
copy of the latest Windows 10 ISO.
To download this ISO, see the article
[How to Download Official Windows 10 ISO file from Microsoft](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/9230-download-windows-10-iso-file.html).

However, my personal recommendation would be to not bother with those chancy
repairs, and instead do a total repair of Windows to set all components to a
known state. I say this because my worry is that the corruption is not limited
to Windows Update.

See for that the article
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This operation will conserve your data, applications and most Windows settings.
However, as this is a serious operation, better ensure first that you have
backups for your data, just in case.